# How do I export a single pose to FBX?

Tags: export

I have a model (Rinky from Big Buck Bunny) that I want to export to FBX for use in Unity. I only need a static model, no walk cycles or anything. I have posed the model and saved the pose in the pose library (there is only one pose in the library). But when I export to FBX, I get the rest pose.

How can I get my custom pose rather than the rest pose when exporting to FBX?

*Suggested tags: fbx, pose*

Comment: related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28475/how-to-save-pose

Answer (score 1):

One rough way could be to apply the pose as rest pose (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and then export. Then undo if you wish to revert to the original rest pose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today (although for MonoGame instead of Unity) and the trick with applying the pose as rest pose didn't work.

Instead you can go into the model mesh and apply the *Armature* modifier.

If the Mesh is the same in *Object-Mode* as in *Edit-Mode* you can export the mesh as a FBX file.